# Is Facebook actively blocking emojis?

Tags: facebook, google-plus, unicode, emoji

When I post all emojis that are available in OSX Mountain Lion on Google+, I get this (Safari screenshot):

[image: Google+]

When I do exactly the same on Facebook I get this (Safari screenshot):

[image: Facebook]

Is it possible that due to some technical limitation most elements of the emoji character set cannot be posted to Facebook or is it more likely that Facebook is actively blocking most of them?